# How to rotate a MapImage with ArcGIS Javascript API

Tags: javascript, arcgis, geo, arcgis-js-api

I created a map and added a `MapImage` trough a `MapImageLayer`. Now I want to rotate the image by a certain angle on the map. How is this possible?
Or is there an other way to add a rotated image to a map?

```js
var map;
require(["esri/geometry/Extent", "esri/geometry/geometryEngine", "esri/layers/MapImageLayer", "esri/layers/MapImage",
  "esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Extent, geometryEngine, MapImageLayer, MapImage, Map) {

  map = new Map("map", {
    basemap: "topo",
    center: [-80.93, 31.47],
    zoom: 4
  });

  var mil = new MapImageLayer({
    'id': 'image_layer'
  });

  var mi = new MapImage({
    'extent': {
      'xmin': -8864908,
      'ymin': 3085443,
      'xmax': -8062763,
      'ymax': 3976997,
      'spatialReference': {
        'wkid': 3857
      }
    },
    'href': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Tux.png'
  });

  mil.addImage(mi);
  map.addLayer(mil);
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <title>Simple Image Service</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/esri/css/esri.css" />
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Couldn't you rotate the image itself before adding it to the map (and then add the rotated image)?

Comment: did you find any solution to this? eventually? I have the same issue, I am loading a map image, I can move the map image around. but rotation is most difficult. My guess is probably rotate server side, and return the rotated image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Using Css we can try to rotate the image.

However esri **esri/layers/MapImageLayer** expect className property where you can pass your expected css properties.

This CSS properties applies on the whole layer not only at one image.

> Below running code will explain how to achieve this:

```js
var map;
require(["esri/geometry/Extent", "esri/geometry/geometryEngine", "esri/layers/MapImageLayer", "esri/layers/MapImage",
  "esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Extent, geometryEngine, MapImageLayer, MapImage, Map) {

  map = new Map("map", {
    basemap: "topo",
    center: [-80, 25],
    zoom: 4
  });

  var mil = new MapImageLayer({
    'id': 'image_layer',
      'className':'rotateClass'
  });

  var mi = new MapImage({
    'extent': {
      'xmin': -8864908,
      'ymin': 3085443,
      'xmax': -8062763,
      'ymax': 3976997,
      'spatialReference': {
        'wkid': 3857
      }
    },
    'href': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Tux.png'
  });

  mil.addImage(mi);
  map.addLayer(mil);
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

 .rotateClass {
    -ms-transform: rotate(15deg) !important; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg) !important; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(15deg) !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <title>Simple Image Service</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/esri/css/esri.css" />
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Hope this will help you :)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But why is the image not fixed to a specific point on the map anymore? Do I need to add some further CSS in order to fix the image like it is in my example?

Comment: As i mentioned above CSS properties applies on the whole layer. So the entire layer container rotates in this case.

Comment: If you don't want to rotate this one image then set image co-ordinates as center of the map.(though this will be a hack)

Comment: Nice hack! But I need to place the image at an exact location on the map. This would be very difficult to achieve with this hack. So I came to the conclusion, that it isn't really possible to place and rotate an image precisely on the map, without using an ArcGIS online service. I guess this is a strategy from ESRI in order to sell their payed services.