# Rotation, scaling Polyline on esri map in javascript api

Tags: arcgis, esri

Is it possible to rotate/scale/translate esri layer with polyline in javascript api 4.0 (or 3.16)?

I see they are just svg object but can't find appropriate api to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really unterstanding your question. What do you mean with scale/translate? I mean... one is scaling and translating while zooming und panning the map. More information about your problem/question would be very helpful.

If you're asking for scaling/translating the polyline itself, you have to access the feature and it's geomtry. Have a look on the [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer.html).

Otherwise if you really mean the whole layer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453652/how-to-rotate-a-mapimage-with-arcgis-javascript-api) is at least another question with an answer how to rotate. Possivbly this works also on other layer-types.